# Can I make windows cache files from disk in RAM?

Tags: windows-10, memory, cache, ramdisk

Linux and OS X are caching files from disk in RAM, whenever you have unused memory. Is there a way to do the same in Windows 10? Right now it's doing its best to keep my memory usage at 33% or 45% all the time, by compressing things.

Would putting temporary files on a ramdisk have the effect I want, albeit with a static size?

Comment: Windows does this also.  Software exists that can create, a RAMDisks, if you want.  No; I won't provide any specific suggestions.

Comment: For developers, check out the new DevDrive feature in Windows 11. Nothing to do with RAM disks, but I mention it because it can help speed up file access to exactly the sort of files that somebody looking at RAM disks is probably looking to speed up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-drive/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is already happening. Here is a snip from Task manager memory usage. Notice the cached number of 2.3 GB.

[image: Task Manager snip showing 2.2GB cache.]

Comment: Yep, there's a 19 there, thx :)

Comment: Note that what task manager shows as "Cached" is not all being used for file cache (some of it is the page cache). There are also cached file contents in the system cache. This does not show up anywhere in Task Manager, but it is visible in PerfMon as the `System Cache Resident Bytes` counter under the Memory object. This is the "reactive" file cache, which has been in the OS since first release (NT 3.1). The part of Task Manager's "cached" that is cacheing files is being used by SuperFetch, which was new with Vista and is a "proactive" cache.

Comment: That's so badly named I've never realized what it was! It definitely needs a tooltip.